# Как склеить скрипты es5 с помощью webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack2

У меня есть несколько библиотек написанных на es5, то есть в них нет директив export. 
Чтобы подключить их к своему проекту я использую 
require ('./source/safeframe/src/js/lib/base');
И вроде бы всё работает, но периодически в консоле браузера появляются ошибки вида (data is not defined). Если я просто подключаю библиотеки через тег < script src="" > то ошибок нет, из чего предполагаю что у меня неправильно настроена сборка. 
Подскажите что делаю не так или что почитать на эту тему. Спасибо

```
context: __dirname + "/src",
entry: {   
    index: "./index",
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: "[name]"
},
watch: NODE_ENV == 'development',
watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
},
devtool: NODE_ENV == 'development' ? "cheap-inline-module-source-map" : null,
plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({   
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
    }),
],
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader:  'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'
    }]
}
```

Сами библиотеки которые пытаюсь использовать
https://sourceforge.net/projects/safeframes/files/